# Indexing is not properly working in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame with itemid column is bold when printed in the notebook.

```
itemid   |  user_id  | day1   | day2      
0        |  1232     | 5      | 3
1        |  4107     | 5      | 3
2        |  9262     | 5      | 3
3        |  1031     | 5      | 3
```

Then I reset the its index using this:

```
df.index.name = None
```

But, then I still have the same dataframe. Then, I reset its index using:

```
df= df.set_index('user_id')
```

Then, I get this:

```
item_id  | day1   | day2    
user_id  
1232     | 5      | 3
4107     | 5      | 3
9262     | 5      | 3
1031     | 5      | 3
```

I have no idea why `item_id` still stays there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `itemid` is the name of your columns, you can try:

```
df.columns.name = None
```

Comment: IThanks for the answer! is this going to destroy all the column names? I would not prefer because I need them.

Comment: No. The column headers still stay. It's just the name of your columns headers will be removed. And you will get a data frame whose index has no name when you stack your data frame.

Comment: Yes  `df.columns` gives the column index or columns headers which are the names of all the columns. But all the columns headers have another name attribute which is the one you are trying to remove here.